# PHP File Upload not working on Mac test bed

Tags: php, macos, file-upload, phpstorm

I'm trying to learn how to upload files in PHP. I installed the latest version of MAMP on OS X Yosemite 10.10.5, today. It defaulted to PHP 7. 
The following code, which is a slight modification from W3C didn't work:

```
<?php
/**
 * File: upload.php
 * Description:
 *
 * @author David Brodersen.
 * @version:
 * @date: 12/16/15
 */
echo 'Outputting $_POST:' . '<br />';
print_r($_POST);

echo '<br /><br />Outputting $_FILES["userfile"]:' . '<br />';
print_r($_FILES['userfile']);

echo '<br />User file stats:<br />';

echo 'name: ' . $_FILES['userfile']['name'] . '<br />';
echo 'type: ' . $_FILES['userfile']['type'] . '<br />';
echo 'size: ' . $_FILES['userfile']['size'] . '<br />';
echo 'tmp_name: ' . $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] . '<br />';
echo 'error: ' . $_FILES['userfile']['error'] . '<br /><br /><br />';

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Upload</title>
</head>

<body>
<!-- The data encoding type, enctype, MUST be specified as below -->
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
    <!-- MAX_FILE_SIZE must precede the file input field -->
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="300000"/>
    <!-- Name of input element determines name in $_FILES array -->
    Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file"/> <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Send File"/>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

I'm using PHP Storm 10. When I launch the app using the PHP Storm link to Chrome. When the web page opens I get the expected:

```
Outputting $_POST:
Array ( ) 

Outputting $_FILES["userfile"]:

User file stats:
name: 
type: 
size: 
tmp_name: 
error:
```

I choose a 300 kb image file and pick 'send file'. The spinner in the tab spins for a while then the page updates to the same state as it was when it was first opened. No statistics are reported. In the configuration for PHP Storm I'm using the php-cgi Interpreter for PHP 7.

Comment: What sort of URLs are you using there?

Answer (score 1):

Check out these values in `php.ini` file :

- `post_max_size`
- `upload_max_filesize`

For MAMP you can find `php.ini` in this path usually :

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/{PHP Version}/conf/php.ini
```

**P.S:** For shared server and you can't access `php.ini` file, You can override them using `.htaccess` file like this:

```
php_value post_max_size 30M
php_value upload_max_filesize 30M
```

If this solution not worked for you, you may need to contact your host provider, Because he may didn't allow you to change php.ini values.